# Drupal pass argument to page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom Drupal module displaying some data in a table.  Each row has a link which if clicked will delete the relevant row.  Specifically, when the link is clicked it will take the user to a confirmation page.  This page is really just a drupal form which says 'are you sure' with two buttons: 'Yes', 'No'. I figure I will need to pass the rowID to the confirmation page.

My question: What is the typically way to pass data to a new page in Drupal 7?  I guess I could just add the rowID to the URL and use the $_GET[] from the confirmation page... I don't think this is very safe and was wondering if there was a better 'Drupal' way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd use something like the following

```
<?php
function yourmod_menu() {
  // for examlple
  $items['yourmod/foo/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete a foo',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('youmode_foo_delete_confirm', 2), // 2 is the position of foo_id
    'access arguments' => array('delete foo rows'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function yourmod_foo_delete_confirm($form, &$form_state, $foo_id) {
  // load the row
  $foo = yourmod_get_foo($foo_id);

  // build your form, if you need to add anything to the confirm form
  // ....
  // Then use drupal's confirm form
  return confirm_form($form,
                  t('Are you sure you want to delete the foo %title?',
                  array('%title' => $foo->title)),
                  'path/to/redirect',
                  t('Some description.'),
                  t('Delete'),
                  t('Cancel'));

}

?>
```

You can look here for examples of [how core modules do it](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/confirm) (have look at node_delete_confirm)

Comment: Also note that for Drupal 7, there is an entity system. So if your "rows" are domain entities you should consider using the Entity api as it would ease a lot of your coding, especialy if you rely on this module http://drupal.org/project/entity

Comment: Thanks, this helped get me on the right track.
I found a good tutorial here:
http://www.akchauhan.com/create-an-action-confirm-form-using-confirm_form-function-in-drupal/

Comment: I've found an awesome example in this video tutorial: http://buildamodule.com/video/drupal-7-core-concepts-how-to-add-and-manipulate-pages-with-the-menu-system-how-to-use-placehoders-to-pass-arguments-in-the-middle-of-a-path

Comment: For Drupal 6, it works almost the same but the confirm function would be `function yourmod_foo_delete_confirm($form_state, $foo_id)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use an existing module created for this purpose:

- http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate (for entity references)
- http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url (for node references)
- http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate (for other form values)

You can configure which form values can be set from the URL, then rewrite the fields displayed in your table to generate the necessary links.

Answer (score 0):

If the data are nodes, you can make the link node/%/delete where % is the nid. Drupal knows how to handle the delete page, as its a core path. Then, the delete confirmation follows the rest of the system and is very 'Drupal'.

I am not sure if this changed at all in Drupal 7, but this is what I did for countless modules.

Comment: Its basically a row in a MySQL table, not a node...  so I don't think thats what I'm looking for

Comment: How is the data getting into the system if its not node related? Anyway then, you would just make up mymodule/%/delete as a menu hook where % is the row ID. That page would call drupal_get_form with a confirmation form, and hook_submit processes that.

Comment: its somewhat an application using Drupal to handle the tedious stuff like like user management and themes.  Data gets in by an insert statement.